Generate 3D graphics with fractal geometry slices like Julia set
Each slice is an approximate curve of JuliaSet and the entire surface is "smooth".

The specific difficulty is

julia set is a fractal function of iteration, it cannot expressed as the parametric equations
Suppose the function equation is F(Z) on the plane of height Z, due to fractal isn’t Differential derivation, dZ maybe nonexistence. ( The parameter Z, as for its magnitude and position and forms is arbitrary, just make the graphics look variable.)
The existing JuliaSetPlot function cannot be linked as an graphics element and other drawing functions like ParametricPlot3D

Manipulate[
 JuliaSetPlot[(x + z) + I  (y + 0.5 z), 
  ColorFunction -> None], 
  {{x, 0, "Re"}, -1, 1},
  {{y, .5, "Im"}, 0, 1}, 
  {{z, 0, "inc"}, -.5, 0}]

here is the author, you can download this 3d file: Julia Vase #001 - Aqua | 3D CAD Model Library | GrabCAD
As an aside, when I try to import the geometry and view the slice view, it becomes very very slow :Slice through Graphics3D

Won't be able to try this out for awhile, but one thought is that you can turn each graphic object that results from each JuliaSetPlot into an image (use Image or maybe ImageData, not sure which would be better). You'll probably need to add the z-height data manually. Once you have all of that, you should be able to use Image3D. Not sure if that has the kind of image quality you want, but might get you started on a trail that will get you where you want.

Would you please clarify what you are really asking? The surface in the image looks very smooth and I cannot believe that "each slice is a Julia set".
You want to know is how to get a parametrized smooth curve/surface which somewhat looks like a julia set?

@A.Kato Yes,that's I need. The slice is  approximated by a smooth curve. The problem is how to satisfy both slices and surfaces to be "smooth".

Thanks for quick response. Then, I recommend you to edit your question accordingly. The meaning of the vertical coordinate is not clear. Maybe you want this, too.


test the GradientFittedMesh approach.

Clear["Global`*"];
pt[z_] := 
 JuliaSetPoints[(x + z) + I (y + 0.5 z) /. {x -> 0, y -> .5}]
zfactor = 10;
pts = Flatten[
   Table[PadRight[#, 3, zfactor*z] & /@ 
     pt[z][[1 ;; -1 ;; 20]], {z, -.5, 0, .01}], 1];
g = RegionPlot3D[GradientFittedMesh@pts, Mesh -> {{zfactor (-.25)}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[5]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.2], Cyan}, Boxed -> False]
Grid[{{Graphics[Point@pt[-.25]], Show[g, ViewPoint -> Top]}}]


